# Ajax not working in text field

Tags: 8, hooks, ajax

I made custom module that implements `hook_form_alter` that marks the `field_text_field_1` textfield as `Ajax-enabled`. When a key is pressed inside the `field_text_field_1`, it should change the value in a second textfield: `field_text_field_2`.

```
$form['#prefix'] = '<div id="my_form_submit_wrapper">';
$form['#suffix'] = '</div>';


// $form['field_village']['#attributes']['id'] = 'edit-field-cities-wrapper';

$form['field_text_field_1']['widget']['#ajax'] =array(
    "callback" => "ajax_change1",
    'wrapper' => 'my_form_submit_wrapper',
    "event" => "change",
    "effect" => "fade",
);
```

The callback function:

```
function ajax_change1(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state){
      $form['field_text_field_2']['widget'][0]['value']['#value']='hello';  
      return $form;
}
```

But it's not changing the value of `field_text_field_2 to "hello".

Comment: prob instead of `#value` it needs to be `#default_value`

Comment: Yea i also used `  $form['field_text_field_2']['widget']['0']['value']['#default_value'] `  but not work ..if above same thing i doing in select field it's work but not on text field.

Comment: Then `field_text_field_2` must be wrong machine name.

Comment: `field_text_field_2` is machine name and it's give output value when i used select field machine name . I think for text field any other way to call ajax.

Comment: Now i leave this problem and i am using jquery ajax for that problem. let's see

Comment: Don't change fields in the AJAX callback, the results won't be saved. Always change it in the form build based on a form state variable.

Comment: Thank you so much sir, for your valuable time. I am trying..

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare on what object (or class if static) to call the callback, like

```
'callback' => [get_called_class(), 'settingsAjax']
```

or

```
'#ajax' => [
            'callback' => [get_class($this), 'addMoreAjax'],
            'wrapper' => $wrapper_id,
            'effect' => 'fade',
          ],
```

or at least

```
'callback' => '::settingsAjax'
```

depending on your code.

Answer (score 0):

> Don't change fields in the AJAX callback, the results won't be saved.
>   Always change it in the form build based on a form state variable. - Clive

I think this is what he is referring to

```
$form['#prefix'] = '<div id="my_form_submit_wrapper">';
$form['#suffix'] = '</div>';


// $form['field_village']['#attributes']['id'] = 'edit-field-cities-wrapper';

$form['field_text_field_1']['widget']['#ajax'] =array(
    "callback" => '::ajax_change1',
    'wrapper' => 'my_form_submit_wrapper',
    "event" => "change",
    "effect" => "fade",
);

if (!empty($form_state->get('field_text_field_2')) {
    $form['field_text_field_2']['widget'][0]['value']['#default_value'] = $form_state->get('field_text_field_2');
}

function ajax_change1(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state){
    $form_state->set('field_text_field_2', 'hello');
    return $form;
}
```

Comment: Actually I have a email field and i want to validate that by ajax call. If user already exist than focus out time give message if already exist

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong on my code i don't know. I have done  this:

```
     $form['field_full_name']['#prefix']="<div id='email-id-validation'>";
     $form['field_full_name']['#suffix']='</div>';

      $form['field_email']['widget']['#ajax'] =array(
      "callback" => "ajax_change",
      'wrapper' => 'email-id-validation',
      "event" => "change",
      "effect" => "fade",
      );
```

And on callback i have done this code:

```
  function ajax_change(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state){
           $form['field_full_name']['widget'][0]['value']['#value']='hello';    
       return $form;  }
```

Simply first i want to check if email field focus out than hello value is print on `$form['field_full_name']` or not.